# ExpressJS to ejs, getting HTTP 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have the following code, but I'm getting HTTP 500 error and the page is being re-directed to error.ejs.

However, the console.log(body) works fine. The problem is being seen in res.render. I'm unable to see any error in console (Tried by setting the env=development too)

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  // Set the headers
  var headers = {
    'Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

  // Configure the request
  var options = {
    url: 'http://External_Web_Service_REST_URL',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
  }

  var result;

  // Start the request
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Print out the response body
      result = body;
      console.log(result); //This works
    }
  })

  res.render('in', {
    title: JSON.parse(result)
  }); //Problem seen here, No logs printed
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `res.render` is executed before `request` call completes.
Remember `request` is async. The fix is to move `res.render` inside `request` callback

```
....
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Print out the response body
      result = body;
      console.log(result); //This works

      //respond from here
      res.render('in', {
        .parse(result)
      }); 
    } else {
      res.render('error'); 
    }
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: For few requests I still see an HTTP 500 error. (console.log(result) works fine). Any pointers please ?